# Xampp/PHPMyAdmin login issues

Tags: phpmyadmin

i know there are many topics and i read at least 40 of it, but none solved my Problem.. I can login to PHPMyAdmin only from the machine its running on... On others there is just an "Access denied". I created a new User with Hostname "%". And i can login with it.

But noone else. They all get that @localhost added, which obviously cant work.

If i change the "host" in the "config.inc.php" to my IPv6 Adress or a dyndns, it adds my fritz.box name instead of "localhost" to it. If i put the fritz.box name in the URL of my browser, i see the dashboard from Xampp, but PHPmyAdmin still gets Access denied.. Im out of ideas, what to search, what to try...

What else can i do?

[User creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSIx6.png)
[Config File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kscf.png)

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986635/create-a-new-mysql-user-in-xampp you have an answer for your 'problem'.

Comment: It doesnt work. If the IP is localhost, all works for me. If i use the IP none works. The User is created right within PHPMyAdmin with the "%" as Hostname, such everyone should be able to access it. But i still get the denied. Or i missed the keything

Comment: Are you trying to connect from other computer in your LAN? If yes, try to use, for example: 10.10.10.% as a hostname. It means - from all IPs in network 10.10.10.0/24.

Comment: No, over the Internet. Its for creating a Database for Testing a PHP-Website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i solved it after 3 other Students tried to help me.

Problem was the Password. It was created with the same Generator as Root, which works, but had some other Symbols like " in it. After changing it to have same Symbols as Root-PW it worked.. So Problem was just the PW.. How should i know that